# How to redirect a URL to a local file?

Tags: windows-7, http, redirection

I am trying to make Windows access `C:\authrootstl.cab` when it tries to GET `http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootstl.cab`.
Is it possible?

Comment: Is this done using a browser?

Comment: @Arjan no, it's done automatically and without showing it to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Edit `%Windows%/System32/driver/etc/hosts`

  - add `127.0.0.1 www.download.windowsupdate.com`
- Install a local webserver (e.g [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/platform/windows.html))

  - configure it to serve the file

    - set the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) to (say) c:\temp
    - either copy `C:\authrootstl.cab` to `C:\Temp\msdownload\update\v3\static\trustedr\en\authrootstl.cab`
    - or configure a URL [rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) rule

Without the rewriting rules you could use any simple HTTP server, such as [tthttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/). You could also use IIS etc etc

Comment: This would rewrite all files from `www.download.windowsupdate.com` to localhost; don't know if that's a problem. If so, then combining Fidler with a local web server might do the trick.

Comment: True, You could get Apache to reverse proxy the others (using an IP-address for the `www.download.windowsupdate.com`. Not sure how deep a rathole is justified by the need to fake the cab file.

Comment: is it possible without a web server?

Comment: It isn't possible without a HTTP server because the client is attempting to connect using HTTP. However the HTTP server need not be on the same PC, it could be any web server anywhere, to which you have access to either the main configuration or (in Apache terms) to a vhost configuration. You still have to change `hosts` on the PC to direct it to the IP-address of the webserver you control.